# Inserting HTML Table Row "Heading" Based On Dynamic Visible Element Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a table containing rows which contain a table cell having a data-time attribute and may or may not be visible (ie. display: none). This visibility is dynamic and at any point a row may change.

Only the first of three table cell in these rows contains a data-time attribute.

The table rows are already grouped according to their children's data-time attribute value. My goal is to utilize JS/jQuery to insert a new table row above the **first/unique visible** occurrence of any particular data-time value. This row should contain a table cell which spans the entire width of the table and has text equivalent to the corresponding data-time value.

Example start:

```
<table>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td data-time="7:15 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="9:30 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td data-time="9:30 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Example goal:

```
<table>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td data-time="7:15 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">8:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="8:00 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">9:30 pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-time="9:30 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td data-time="9:30 pm"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Iterate through the rows and store the date-time value. Compare this to the last seen date-time value. If different, then insert a new row about it, and update the last-seen date-time value. If not different, then just go on to the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:-

http://jsfiddle.net/9XTat/

```
   $('#addRow').click(function(){
     $('td[data-time]',$('tr').not('tr[style="display:none;"]')).each(function(i,o){
        var lastelement = $('td[data-time="' + $(this).data('time') + '"]').first();

        if((lastelement.parent('tr').prev('tr.textRow')).length == 0)
        {
        var newelement = '<tr class="textRow"><td colspan="3">' + $(this).data('time') + '</td> </tr>'
        lastelement.parent().before(newelement);
        }

    });
```